# Tool to check for illegal characters in bibtex/biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, characters

Is there a tool to check for illegal characters, and ideally convert them into something that bibtex/biblatex allows? For example once, I realised that I had Unicode U+200A spaces, so I had to manually go through the entry, deleting the spaces and then putting in a new allowed whitespace; what a nightmare! Most recently I am getting the error `BibTeX: warning: 1 characters of junk seen at toplevel` next to one of my entries, but it does not give me any more clues than that.

My `bibliography.bib` file has the entry

```
@article{Sanvitto2016,
    title        = {The road towards polaritonic devices},
    author       = {Sanvitto, Daniele and K{\'e}na-Cohen, St{\'e}phane},
    year         = 2016,
    journal      = {Nature Materials},
    volume       = 15,
    number       = 10,
    pages        = {1061--1073},
    issn         = {1476-4660},
    url          = {https://doi.org/10.1038/nmat4668}
}
```

The releavant parts of my `main.tex` file are

```
\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography}
...
\printbibliography
```

I am also using a custom `.cls` and `.sty` file provided by the journal, but I don't know if that is relevant.

Comment: Your write-up is somewhat confusing. E.g., you specify biblatex option `backend=biber`, but then you report an error message generated by BibTeX. Please clarify.

Comment: Hmm. Well this is indeed how my .tex file is setup, and that is the error I am getting. I am using Overleaf. Sorry to not be more helpful.

Comment: If I change to `\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}` I get the same error. So I will update the question to remove this complication / point of confusion.

Comment: You don't need to remove all U+200A from your bib-file. You need to define it once to give a sensible output (actually I think it is already defined in a current latex, but I can't test now).